# firebase and typescript - Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Message'

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

It's my first time using typescript, so I've decided use it with Firebase.
But I'm facing errors that I'm not able to understand.

I wrote two files `MessageTemplate.ts` and `test.ts` 
After run them everything works fine.

But when I'm trying to push(firebase deploy --only functions) them to firebase-functions I have the following errors:

```
> tsc

src/index.ts:18:25 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Message'.
  Property 'condition' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'ConditionMessage'.

18  admin.messaging().send(payload)
                           ~~~~~~~

  node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.d.ts:410:3
    410   condition: string;
          ~~~~~~~~~
    'condition' is declared here.

src/index.ts:19:11 - error TS7006: Parameter 'fcm_response' implicitly has an 'any' type.

19    .then((fcm_response) => {
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/index.ts:24:12 - error TS7006: Parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type.

24    .catch((error) => {
              ~~~~~

src/MessageTemplate.ts:37:5 - error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.

37     payload["notification"] = notification.toJSON()
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/MessageTemplate.ts:37:31 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

37     payload["notification"] = notification.toJSON()
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/MessageTemplate.ts:41:5 - error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.

41     payload["data"] = data
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/MessageTemplate.ts:44:3 - error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.

44   payload[type] = to
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 7 errors.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /somepath/_logs/2019-03-26T21_04_51_135Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
```

functions/src/index.ts

```
import { buildPushNotification, SenderType } from "./MessageTemplate";
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();



export const sendMessage = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    // The topic name can be optionally prefixed with "/topics/".
    let topic = 'global'
    let data = {
        id:1024,
        name:"Juan"
    }
    let payload = buildPushNotification(SenderType.topic, topic, undefined, data)

    // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
    admin.messaging().send(payload)
      .then((fcm_response) => {
        // Response is a message ID string.
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', fcm_response);
        response.send("Successfully sent message");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        response.send("Error");
      });
});
```

MessageTemplate.ts

```
export enum SenderType {
  token="token", 
  topic="topic", 
  condition="condition"
}

export class PNotification {

    title:string
    body:string

    constructor(title:string, body:string) { 
      this.title = title 
      this.body = body
  }

  toJSON():any {
    return {
      "title":this.title,
      "body":this.body
    }
  } 
}

function isNullOrUndefined(data:any){
  return data === null || typeof data === 'undefined' 
}

export function buildPushNotification(type:SenderType, to:string, notification?:PNotification, data?:any){

  let payload = {}

  if(!isNullOrUndefined(notification)) {
    payload["notification"] = notification.toJSON()
  }

  if(!isNullOrUndefined(data)) {
    payload["data"] = data
  }

  payload[type] = to

  return payload
}
```

test.ts

```
import { PNotification, buildPushNotification, SenderType } from "./MessageTemplate";



let notification = new PNotification("title 1", "body 1")
let data = {
    id:1024,
    name:"Juan"
}

let to = "AISA143f43533d32d3243d546fwf234"
let topic = "global"

let payload1 = buildPushNotification(SenderType.token, to, notification)
console.log(payload1)
```

functions/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2015"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using the same `tsconfig.json` when you run and when you try to push?

Comment: I didn't know even exist a tsconfig.json. Well I've just read about it and I've updated with the firebase functions/tsconfig.json. Answering your question: I'm not using the same tsconfig.json, actually, after run tsc MessageTemplate.ts i don't have any tsconfig.json in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

When you run locally, since you are not using a `tsconfig.json`, the compiler is using less strict settings than when you try to push, where there is a `tsconfig.json` with some of the available strict options enabled, i.e. `strict`, `noImplicitReturns` and `noUnusedLocals`.

Here is the documentation for [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) and [the compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

To show the `strict` errors in the files that you successfully compiled locally, I have added them to a single file in a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20enum%20SenderType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20token%20%3D%20%22token%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20topic%20%3D%20%22topic%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20condition%20%3D%20%22condition%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20PNotification%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20body%3A%20string%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(title%3A%20string%2C%20body%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.title%20%3D%20title%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.body%20%3D%20body%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20toJSON()%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20this.title%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22body%22%3A%20this.body%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isNullOrUndefined(data%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20data%20%3D%3D%3D%20null%20%7C%7C%20typeof%20data%20%3D%3D%3D%20'undefined'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20buildPushNotification(type%3A%20SenderType%2C%20to%3A%20string%2C%20notification%3F%3A%20PNotification%2C%20data%3F%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20payload%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(!isNullOrUndefined(notification))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%5B%22notification%22%5D%20%3D%20notification.toJSON()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(!isNullOrUndefined(data))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%5B%22data%22%5D%20%3D%20data%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%5Btype%5D%20%3D%20to%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20payload%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20notification%20%3D%20new%20PNotification(%22title%201%22%2C%20%22body%201%22)%0D%0Alet%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%201024%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22Juan%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20to%20%3D%20%22AISA143f43533d32d3243d546fwf234%22%0D%0Alet%20topic%20%3D%20%22global%22%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20payload1%20%3D%20buildPushNotification(SenderType.token%2C%20to%2C%20notification)%0D%0Aconsole.log(payload1)). If you click the `Options` button and enable the strict options you will see the errors.

Here is [another Playground with the errors removed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20enum%20SenderType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20token%20%3D%20%22token%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20topic%20%3D%20%22topic%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20condition%20%3D%20%22condition%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20PNotification%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20body%3A%20string%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(title%3A%20string%2C%20body%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.title%20%3D%20title%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.body%20%3D%20body%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20toJSON()%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22title%22%3A%20this.title%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22body%22%3A%20this.body%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isNullOrUndefined(data%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20data%20%3D%3D%3D%20null%20%7C%7C%20typeof%20data%20%3D%3D%3D%20'undefined'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20function%20buildPushNotification(type%3A%20SenderType%2C%20to%3A%20string%2C%20notification%3F%3A%20PNotification%2C%20data%3F%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20Payload%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20notification%3F%3A%20any%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3F%3A%20any%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20token%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20topic%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20condition%3F%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20payload%3A%20Payload%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(!isNullOrUndefined(notification))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(notification%20instanceof%20PNotification)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload.notification%20%3D%20notification.toJSON()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(!isNullOrUndefined(data))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%5B%22data%22%5D%20%3D%20data%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20payload%5Btype%5D%20%3D%20to%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20payload%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20notification%20%3D%20new%20PNotification(%22title%201%22%2C%20%22body%201%22)%0D%0Alet%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%201024%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22Juan%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20to%20%3D%20%22AISA143f43533d32d3243d546fwf234%22%0D%0Alet%20topic%20%3D%20%22global%22%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20payload1%20%3D%20buildPushNotification(SenderType.token%2C%20to%2C%20notification)%0D%0Aconsole.log(payload1)).

To fix the `payload[...]` left-hand-side errors, I added an interface:

```
interface Payload {
    notification?: any
    data?: any
    token?: string
    topic?: string
    condition?: string
}
```

This defines the types for each of the possible properties, which are all optional, as they include `?`.

The `payload` declaration now becomes:

```
let payload: Payload = {}
```

As `payload` and its properties have now been typed, the `noImplicitAny` errors have been fixed.

To fix the `notification.toJSON` right-hand-side error, I added a type guard, to ensure that `notification` is the right type:

```
if (!isNullOrUndefined(notification)) {
    if (notification instanceof PNotification) {
        payload.notification = notification.toJSON()
    }
}
```

You may wish to change the `isNullOrUndefined` function instead of using this. If so, you could use a user-defined type guard (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Advanced%20Types.md#user-defined-type-guards) and [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html#user-defined-type-guards)).

To fix the other errors, I would recommend using vscode or similar, with the same `tsconfig.json` as you have on Firebase, so you can see the errors locally and be shown potential fixes in the editor. Alternatively, if you prefer and are able to, you could remove the strict settings from the Firebase `tsconfig.json`.